# FB and Google Login not working

Tags: android

My app is already in playstore, I made an update in the app using another system (having a different SHA1 key) after a long time.

App's Facebook and Google Login not working while testing.

Can I add another SHA1 key in app and in console will it work?
If yes how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, For debug (testing) purpose go to facebook dev console and append your debug keyhash from your current system. More info :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android